# How to connect multiple storyboards to single viewcontroler.swift file?

Tags: ios, swift

I have different `ViewController`(storyboard) every `storyboard` will present the different `tableView` but each have the same source, how is it possible to connect all the `storyboard` to same `ViewController.swift` file.

I am still very new in `Swift` (newbie) please help.

Thank you so much!

Comment: you need to segue one storyboard to another storyboard viewcontroller?

Comment: Can't you set same class for all these view controllers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop individual views into a Storyboard file. For that you should do File > New > View which will create a XIB file.